# Difficult Entity Framework Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a `DbSet<DtoProfile>` .
Now i want to filter my profiles.

My model:

```
public class DtoProfile {
    public IList<DtoLookingFor> LookingFor { get; set; } = new List<DtoLookingFor>();
    public virtual DtoSearch Search { get; set; }
    public Guid? SearchId { get; set; }
}
public class DtoLookingFor
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public LookingFor LookingFor { get; set; }
}
public enum LookingFor
{
    A, B, C, D, E
}
public class DtoSearch
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DtoLookingFor> LookingFor { get; set; }
}
```

Example:
Profile1 has LookingFor A, B, C and search with LookingFor B, C
Profile2 has LookingFor B, D
Profile3 has LookingFor E
Profile1 should get all profiles where LookingFor is B or C. (in example Profile1 and Profile2)

How can i do this with `IQueryable<DtoProfile>` ?
I already have the DtoSearch objected loaded from database and can access with dtoSearch.LookingFor all the DtoLookingFor

Comment: I've added a solution that takes a DtoProfile and returns the matching relevant profiles (including itself - as you wanted) lmk if it works for you or it is not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the Properties named "LookingFor", is really confusing, you have too many of these and it is also the class name.

This working example will bring you if you choose input profile1 --> profile1 + profile2

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DtoProfile> profiles = new List<DtoProfile>();
        var profile1 = new DtoProfile
        {
            LookingFor = new List<DtoLookingFor> { new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.A }, new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.B }, new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.C } },
            Search = new DtoSearch
            {
                LookingFor = new List<DtoLookingFor> { new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.B }, new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.C } },
            },
            SearchId = new Guid("10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
        };

        var profile2 = new DtoProfile
        {
            LookingFor = new List<DtoLookingFor> { new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.B }, new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.D } },
            SearchId = new Guid("20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")

        };

        var profile3 = new DtoProfile
        {
            LookingFor = new List<DtoLookingFor> { new DtoLookingFor { LookingFor = LookingFor.E } },
            SearchId = new Guid("30000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")

        };


        profiles.AddRange(new List<DtoProfile> { profile1, profile2, profile3 });

        IEnumerable<DtoProfile> query = GetMatchesForProfile(profiles, profile1);

        Console.WriteLine("Found: " + string.Join(",", query.Select(m => m.SearchId)));
        //result: Found: 10000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,20000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
    }

    private static IEnumerable<DtoProfile> GetMatchesForProfile(List<DtoProfile> profiles, DtoProfile profileToMatch)
    {
        return profiles.Where(searchProfile => profileToMatch.Search.LookingFor.Any(m => searchProfile.LookingFor.Any(z => z.LookingFor == m.LookingFor)));
    }
```